# Xamarin WatckKit: using normal interface mode only

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, watchkit

When creating a new WatchKit app in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio, there are already controllers for all three modes: normal, glances and notifications.

But I don't need glances and notifications controllers. How to opt-out?

Comment: Can't you just delete them?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge, of course, I can. But I don't understand what is an entry point here? For example, in usual Xamarin.iOS app it's Main method. How it works here? Just by controller name convention?

Comment: I believe that's controlled in the storyboard, but I'm no watchkit expert.